# Screenshot not positioned on mobile device

Tags: html, css

I'm building an app presentation website and currently I'm adding some screenshots to the website, but they are not displaying right on the device.

I think there is something that needs to be changed in CSS, but I'm not sure what. I'm a primarily a mobile app developer, and not very familiar with web development.

Here is the URL of the website: [nishnocu.com](http://nishnocu.com)

If you need more information, let me know.

```css
.device-container.iphone-space-grey {
  background: url('../../img/devices/iphone/6sg.png') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: contain;
}

.device-container.iphone-silver {
  background: url('../../img/devices/iphone/6s.png') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: contain;
}

.device-container.iphone-gold {
  background: url('../../img/devices/iphone/6g.png') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: contain;
}

.device-container.i6 .device-container-inner {
  width: 294px;
  top: 81px;
  left: 28px;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .device-container.i6 .device-container-inner {
    width: 249px;
    top: 68px;
    left: 18px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .device-container.i6 .device-container-inner {
    width: 206px;
    top: 58px;
    left: 62px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .device-container.i6 .device-container-inner {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.device-container.i6 .owl-theme .owl-controls {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--/Visible on XS SM-->
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <!--Device Container-->
  <div class="device-container i6 iphone-silver">
    <div class="device-container-inner">
      <div id="app-showcase" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/cover/screenshot-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Iphone Application 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/cover/screenshot-2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Iphone Application 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="img/cover/screenshot-3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Iphone Application 3" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/Device Container-->
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem? It looks good to me..

Comment: The screenshot is overlapping a little below display

Comment: Hmm, what do you think I should do. I find this template on website and it was free..

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic make your own carousel with an image of a phone and background images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using the inbuilt carousel and other libraries for developing you need to handle manually with help of media query. Just hide the dots of carousel but setting its proptery to false and rest with the below code it will fit into the mobile image.

for > 992px add "border-radius: 4px; height: 438px; width: 247px;" in ".owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer"  for <992px to >767px add "border-radius: 4px; height: 364px; width: 206px;" in ".owl-carousel .owl-wrapper-outer" & for <768px you have not added the Mobile image.

Comment: Stupid question, but is this "for > 992px" related to height or width?

Comment: Nothing is stupid if you are leaning, as i also don't have much of experience. 992 is for width. All the pixels i have mentioned will be used like "@media (max-width: 991px) {}"